# how to manage language redirection for website automatic but keep manual changing?

Tags: apache, magento, internationalization, magento2

I'm dealing with an international magento website.
All languages are located in multiple subdirectory (/fr, /de, /es, and ...)

I'd like to redirect customers on a header of navigator basis, using %{accept-language}.
But i'd like to keep the ability for my customers to change language. Do you how to setup that whith a vhost configuration ?
Or is it mandatory to setup this in PHP and keeping the change in a php session ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the [tag:magento] tag says: _"General Magento questions (like administration) may be asked on https://magento.stackexchange.com Magento is an e-commerce platform written in PHP. Questions should be related to writing code for Magento."_ and this looks like an administrative task. If it's about writing code, then the code (what you've tried so far) is missing, to be on topic.

Comment: i'm was specifying mageto but i'm not sure it should be a magento code solution, also it could be an apache one.

Answer (score 0):

- For multilanguage, you can create a different store view (with specific language code) for all languages.
- For create store view ,
  Go to Admin -> Stores -> All stores
- After create store views for all language go to Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Url Options
  In that select 'Yes' in 'Add store code to Url'. Also, please add a language switcher in the website.